# How to write custom jQuery Code in Vue JS Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I am a bit new to VueJS and using **webpack-simple**, I have made a Sidebar component and put some sidebar code from internet but that sidebar works on jQuery. I searched the internet but I couldn't find the way I can use jQuery code into vue templates, my jQuery code:

```
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function() {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);
  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});

$("#close-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").removeClass("toggled");
});
$("#show-sidebar").click(function() {
  $(".page-wrapper").addClass("toggled");
});
```

**Vue File:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navbar></navbar>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

> **I also added the code directly into the `index.html` file but not worked!**

Comment: May be useful: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @SteffPoint that's working but I am getting one error in the console as **slideUp is not a function!**